# Transition not triggered after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a search modal, it is triggered via jQuery which adds the class `-open` to the main parent div `#search-box`. My issue is that the `#search-box` will fade in however the `input` does not transform. I am not sure why this is happening. [Here is a link to the full codepen](https://codepen.io/simonfricker/pen/EZrxoX)

```
  #search-box {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     z-index: 999999999;

     input {
        border-bottom: 2px solid white;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
        transform-origin: 0% 50%;
        transition: transform 3s;
     }

     &.-open{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
        display: block;
        animation: fadein .8s;

        input{
           transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
           transition-duration: 10s;
           transition-delay: 2s;
         }
      }
  }

@keyframes fadein {
   from { opacity: 0; }
   to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

here is the jquery

```
$('a[href="#search"]').click(function() {
  $("#search-box").addClass("-open");
  setTimeout(function() {
    inputSearch.focus();
  }, 800);
});

$('a[href="#close"]').click(function() {
  $("#search-box").removeClass("-open");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the parent `#search-box` is switching from `display: none` to `block` and css transitions wont trigger on that change.
Some solutions would be to have an `animation` scaling the input element, or hiding the `#search-box` in another way. Like using `height:0; overflow:hidden` or `visibility: hidden` > `visibility: visible`.

Comment: Ah thank you for this useful bit of info. I have updated the codepen and it works. https://codepen.io/simonfricker/pen/EZrxoX

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://codepen.io/adrianroworth/pen/rjPdKj

The reason was that the `display: none` / `display: block` were causing the animations not to work properly. I have changed the way that works to use absolute position to position it off-screen while still being visible.